# ERD including supertype, subtype database

Tags: database, erd, subtype, supertype

I'm drawing an ERD for a  database and want to know if you need to include the supertypes and sub-types in the ERD. If yes, how to represent it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

google for "ER Specialization". This is the term used in ER literature for subtyping.  You should get some ways to diagram it, using the "Is-a" triangle connector.  Some tutorials place it in "Extended ER features".